# XML parsing with Zend's xmlrpc Client

Tags: php, xml, zend-framework, xml-parsing

I am trying to retrieve from an xml file which holds list of the hotel bookings, using zend library called xmlrpc. This is the code:

```
$client = new Zend_XmlRpc_Client('http://username:password@distribution-xml.booking.com/xml-rpc');
$service = $client->getProxy();
$hotels = $service->bookings->getHotels();
```

How can I pass some parameters to the getHotels method?

Comment: I can't help you directly, but here's the documentation: [for the Zend XmlRpc Client](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.xmlrpc.client.html) and for [booking.com's bookings.getHotels](http://distribution-xml.booking.com/affiliates/documentation/xml_gethotels.html)

Comment: I've already read it, but I don't saw any help in the booking's help :s

Comment: Yeah the booking.com documentation sucks. :-/

Comment: sigh, I really need for a stupid example of parameters pass...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done it! Just pass the parameters in an associative array like this:

```
$client = new Zend_XmlRpc_Client('http://username:password@distribution-xml.booking.com/xml-rpc');
$content = array(
    'paramname' => array(paramvalues)
 );
 $service = $client->getProxy(); 
 $hotels=$service->bookings->getHotels($content);

;)
```